# Linear Dependence by Inspection

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, cryptography, coding-theory

I was wondering if it is possible to determine the number of linearly dependent columns of a matrix by inspection. Consider the following matrix
$$H=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1  & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.$$
$H$ has three leading columns. From my understanding, this means there are three linearly independent columns (this can also be seen as neither of the first three columns can be expressed as a linear combination of one another).

Can we determine the number of linearly dependent columns of $H$ in a similar way?

**Question.**

Let $C$ be the binary linear code with generator matrix 
$$G=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.$$
What is the minimal distance $d(C)$?

There exists a theorem which states that the minimum distance for linear codes, $d(C)$, is given by *$d(c)$=min{$r:G$ has $r$ linearly dependent columns}*.

Comment: How would you define "the number of linearly dependent columns"?

Comment: @5xum By example: the third column is equal to the first column plus the fifth column. There are three linearly dependent columns. Does that help?

Comment: Then there are $5$ dependent columns, because each column is a linear combination of the other four. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @5xum From memory, the following definition is used: the vectors $v_1,..,v_n$ are linearly independent if the only values of the scalars $\lambda_1,..,\lambda_n$ satisfie $\lambda_1 v_1+...+\lambda_n v_n=\underline{0}$ where $\lambda_1 =...=\lambda_n=0$.

Comment: Yes, that is the definition of what "linearly independent" means. But I am asking how you define the "number of linearly dependent columns".

Comment: @5xum I thought that if there were two linearly dependent columns, then two columns are scalar multiples of one another. I am not 100% sure what you're asking. My confusion is complicated by the fact that I have not touched linear algebra in a while.

Comment: You are asking: "Can we determine the number of linearly dependent columns of H in a similar way?". What I am asking you is how you define the value "number of linearly dependent columns". I don't know what you mean by that. I am asking you to provide a description of what you mean when you say that. Because I can take any four columns of $H$, and I am certain they will be linearly dependent. And I can take any five columns of $H$, and they will be linearly dependent. So what is the "number of dependent columns" here?

Comment: The point is that linear dependence and independence are properties of _sets_ of vectors, not of individual vectors. One might ask about the minimum size of the linearly-dependent subset of columns, but I’m not sure that’s a particularly interesting value since the presence of a zero column makes that $1$ regardless of the other relationships among the columns.

Comment: Is there some problem that you’re trying to solve that prompted this question? That context could help us figure out what it is you’re asking about here.

Comment: @amd I will include the relevant question. Thanks :)

Comment: Notice that you have 1: No zero column, so no single column is dependent. 2: You do have a repeated column, so you have sets of two dependent columns. This is more difficult when the minimum distance is 3 or larger, but works for small $d$.